# How do I debug from ASP.NET to SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, debugging, ssms

Basically what I want to do is start a debug on a web page and then F10 into cmd.ExecuteNonQuery which would take me to SQL Server/SSMS and allow me to see what the actual stored procedure is doing.

Is there a way to do this (or something like this)?

Comment: use the debugger in SQL Server Management Studio, set a breakpoint in your SP and wait until it gets executed

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use Glimpse http://getglimpse.com/ to profile what is happening. This will show you the SQL being executed as well as a whole heap of other information.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way will be to use the **SQL Server Profiler** in the SSMS (Tool -> SQL Server Profiler).

It will allow you to view the command that your website executed. After tha, if needed, you can copy the command and execute it in a new query with debugging.

You can look at this [MSDN site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) for guides about how to run specific tasks.